# Passing parameters to another domain website's page in javascript without opening it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i am trying to develop a website in .net which will generate ads images. and i can place that images link in any website.then i want to track the no.of views and clicks on that image with the url and other information of the websites where i have placed the ads. now i want to integrate the javascript code to third party websites which will automatically send the information of their site to my domain's page that will accept those values and will save in the database. how can i pass the values from the javascript and get those values in my domain without opening the my domain page in window.Please help me if any one have knowledge about this.Thanks

Comment: You're asking how to build an ad serving engine and the analytics around it.  That's WAY too broad a question for SO.  You can perhaps pick one aspect of this question, research the options and then ask a very specific question about that one aspect if you don't understand something.

Comment: i just want to send some information values from a page of clients website to my domain's page with the help of javascript .then after that i will able to get those values to store in database

Comment: Then, do a search for JSONP on Google.  You will need a cross-domain solution which is why plain AJAX won't work because of same-origin security restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's ajax method to send information to your domain. The method will look like.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",     // GET|POST
    url: remote_url, // your domain url
    async: true,     // set it to false if you want a sync request
    success : function(data) { // you can send back the data processed from your domain back to client side if needed

    }
});
```

Comment: The OP didn't ask for a jQuery answer.

Comment: Thanks Amit,this is how i can send information to my domain. now how can i get these information in my domain page at where i want to store the value in database.

Comment: Rohit, I am not aware of .net so much. But to your server side code you can get the sent values by using request.getParameter("param").
You can send the params in remote_url variable.

Comment: i got it..Thanks Amit for your help..:)